# How to query multiple column using LIKE and OR condition in Firebase Firestore Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to run a Firestore query using `LIKE` and `OR` condition. I couldn't see any examples in the firestore docs too.

There was a section called `Full-Text Search` which recommend a `Algolia` Search.

Is there a way to achieve `LIKE` and `OR` condition in firestore query ?

**Data Model**

[image]

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT * FROM
   Booking
WHERE awbNumber LIKE %searchText%
OR referenceNumber LIKE %searchText%
OR shipperName LIKE %searchText%
OR receiverName LIKE %searchText%
OR origin LIKE %searchText%
OR destination LIKE %searchText%
```

**Firestore Query** using Angular Fire Library

***commented out the code which are tried and not worked.***

```
let query = this.db.collection(doc).ref.orderBy('id', 'desc');

if (searchText) {
        // query = query.(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');

        // query = query.orderBy('awbNumber').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');
        // query = query.orderBy('referenceNumber').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');
        // query = query.orderBy('additionalContacts').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');
        // query = query.orderBy('additionalLeaf').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');
        // query = query.orderBy('additionalWeights').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');
        // query = query.orderBy('deliveryOfficeAddress').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');
        // query = query.orderBy('destination').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');
        // query = query.orderBy('origin').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');
        // query = query.orderBy('receiverName').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');
        // query = query.orderBy('remarks').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');
        // query = query.orderBy('shipperName').startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + '\uf8ff');

        // query = query.where('awbNumber == searchText');
        // query = query.where('referenceNumber', '==', searchText);
        // query = query.where('additionalContacts', '==', searchText);
        // query = query.where('additionalLeaf', '==', searchText);
        // query = query.where('additionalWeights', '==', searchText);
        // query = query.where('deliveryOfficeAddress', '==', searchText);
        // query = query.where('destination', '==', searchText);
        // query = query.where('origin', '==', searchText);
        // query = query.where('receiverName', '==', searchText);
        // query = query.where('remarks', '==', searchText);
        // query = query.where('shipperName', '==', searchText);
      }

query = query.limit(limit);

      return this.db.collection(doc, (ref) => query)
      .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
          map((actions) => actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as any;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data, count };
          }))
        );
```

---

Is there any way to achieve the result that is mentioned in SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: no.

There is no OR operator when querying Firestore (there is some kind of it actually with the `in` and `array-contains-any` when you want to do OR on the same field.
There is no LIKE operator.

If you really need that kind of query, Firestore may not be the best option